# Using classes from target/test-classes

Tags: java, maven, build

I am a newbie to Java/Maven. I have a standard maven project structure, and I've written some helper classes that I want to use in some testing scripts, and those classes are in the `src/test/java`. After I do `mvn clean install`, I can see that those classes are in `target/test-classes`, but in my script although I use the absolute path to the `target` directory in my `CLASSPATH`, I am seeing a `Could not find or load main class ...`.

For instance, I have `src/test/java/validation/CrossValidator.java`, and in my script I am using `java -cp $CLASSPATH validation.CrossValidator ...`, where `CLASSPATH` is the absolute path to `target` directory.

Anyone can guide me to accomplish this? I know that I can simply move those classes to `src/java/main`, but I don't want those classes to be part of the library `jar`, since they're not used at runtime.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why use such script? Since you use maven, let every thing in maven life circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a secondary execution of the maven-jar-plugin that builds a test jar from your project:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This will create a jar with a classifier of `test-jar` that contains all of your test classes.

More details can be found at [Create test JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html#).